# Flutter - only show image if enough space available

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an `Expanded` Widget with an `Image.asset(...)` as it's child.
On small phones there is not enough space and the image is scaled down massively. Since it is only for eye-candy anyways, I'd like to hide / not show the `Image` if there isn't at least a `height >= 100.0` available.

How do I accomplish this in Flutter? Is there a way to get the parent widgets size?

Comment: could you put your code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `LayoutBuilder` to obtain the input constraints of a widget.

Then based on these constraints decide to display or not an image

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraint) {
      if (constraint.maxHeight < 100.0) {
        // too small
        return Container();
      } else {
        // ok
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset("foo"),
            Container()
          ],
        );
      }
  },
)
```

Comment: Awesome! You saved me tons of time!

Answer (score 2):

Awesome Remi's solution, and You can use the MediaQuery and MediaQueryData too, has some properties and methods that can help  your in situations like that.

Some properties are orientation, size, padding, devicePixelRatio, etc.

Example:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).orientation
```

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData-class.html